# Receiving Exception: The getter 'id' was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Hello StackOverflow users,

I got stuck and I am not able to understand why I am receiving this error. So, let me explain me what I am doing,

1. This is my Home Page where my body of the Scaffold is a PageView, In the PageView the first page is TimeLine(currentUser: currentUser) where currentUser stores the details of the User.

### home.dart

```
Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Timeline(currentUser: currentUser),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(currentUser: currentUser),
          Search(),
          Profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
   );
}
```

2. This is TimeLine Page, in this Page I am just trying to print 'currentUser.id' and while doing that I am receiving the exception (The getter 'id' was called on null).

### timeline.dart

```
class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {

  final User currentUser;
  Timeline({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    print('Timeline : ${widget.currentUser.id}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('Timeline'),
    );
  }
}
```

3. I was looking up the code to see why I am receiving the exception and then I want to Upload Page, the 3rd page of the PageView and tried to print 'currentUser.id' and interestingly it worked fine here although I am receiving an exception here too but after that the user.id is getting printed..

### upload.dart

```
class Upload extends StatefulWidget {

  final User currentUser;
  Upload({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _UploadState createState() => _UploadState();
}

class _UploadState extends State<Upload> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Upload : ${widget.currentUser.id}');
    return Scaffold(
        body: Text('Upload'),
    );
  }
}
```

I am confused why this behaviour is happening. If anyone needs more information ping me but I provided the basic structure and I am facing this problem.

[image: console image]

<--Update-->

### Code where I set currentUser

```
void createUserInFirestore() async{

    /* check if user exists in users.collection in database */
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc  = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();


    /* If the user doesn't exist then we will create account */
    if(!doc.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount())
      );

      /* Create new user from userName in users collection */
      usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      });
      doc = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();
    }

    currentUser = User.fromDocument(doc);
    print('Create User in firestore : ${currentUser.id}');
  }
}
```

### User model class

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final  String email;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String displayName;
  final String bio;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.photoUrl,
    this.displayName,
    this.bio,
  });

  factory User.fromDocument(doc) {
    return User(
      id: doc.data()['id'],
      username: doc.data()['username'],
      email: doc.data()['email'],
      photoUrl: doc.data()['photoUrl'],
      displayName: doc.data()['displayName'],
      bio: doc.data()['bio'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't find you assigned value to current user.

Comment: Probably you get currentUser asynchronously from db or http client. If it's true, try to use FutureBuilder. Anyway please provide the code where you set currentUser.

Comment: i think Timeline page will show before set currentUser data into variable

Comment: show the code where you set data into currentUser

Comment: @MuhammadYounas

Sorry for a delayed reply, I have updated the code please look into it.

Comment: @Ashish Please look into the updated code